# App crashes when I load data into Kinvey

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash, kinvey

I have and app and am using kinvey as the backend. I have followed their tutorials and when I try to load the data into the sever it crashes. In the log it says

```
    KinveyEntity.m:69 [ERROR] EXCEPTION Encountered: Name => UnsupportedFeatureException, Reason => This version of the Kinvey iOS library requires clients to override this method
```

(lldb)

I have the user able to change the text being sent. How can I fix this?

Comment: Learn to debug a crash: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Can you upgrade to latest iOS SDK? If that doesn't help, please add code which leads to the crash.